# Moment not extendable with moment-range

Tags: typescript, momentjs, netlify, vite, moment-range

I'm using `"moment": "^2.29.1", "moment-range": "^4.0.2",` to get the range between two dates.

Vite with Vue3 and typescript.

Locally, eveything works fine. But when deploying to Netlify I get the following error:

> Cannot add property range, object is not extensible
> at Object.o [as extendMoment]

Importing moment:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import { extendMoment } from "moment-range";

const Moment = extendMoment(moment);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what let me make moment-range work in both watch and build versions of vite app:

```
import moment from 'moment'
import * as MomentRange from 'moment-range'
const momentJs = MomentRange.extendMoment(moment)
```

Also had to add following to vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            {
                find: 'moment-range',
                replacement: path.resolve("./node_modules/moment-range/dist/moment-range"),
            },
            ...
        ],
    },
})
```